# Decimal('12000') is not JSON serializable

Tags: ajax, json, django, serialization

I have a Django instance running on Apache2.  One of my web pages is doing Ajax callbacks to Django.

Most of the time, it works great, but sometime for a reason I can’t determine, it stops working with the following error from Django:

**Decimal('12000') is not JSON serializable**

Once I received this error once, it stops working forever. The only solution I know is to restart Apache.

The Python/Django is not changing, neither the data requested by the Ajax call. I never had this problem when I run my code on the Django web server.

views.py:

```
@login_required
def KPIInitTable(request):
    kpi_values = [ob.as_json() for ob in KPI.objects.all()]
    data = {'table_data' : kpi_values,
    'colHeaders': ['KPI', 'CityCategory', 'Type','January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    'rowHeaders': 0,
    'KPIList': settings.TST_KPILIST,
    'TypeList': settings.TST_TYPELIST,
    'CityCategoryList': settings.TST_CITYCATEGORYLIST
    }
    response = HttpResponse(dumps(data, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder), mimetype='application/json')
    response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
    return response
```

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models

    class KPI(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
        CityCategory = models.CharField(max_length=50,  null=True)
        type = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)   
        Jan = models.DecimalField( max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True)
        Feb = models.DecimalField( max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True)
        Mar = models.DecimalField( max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True)
        Apr = models.DecimalField( max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True)
        May = models.DecimalField( max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True)
        Jun = models.DecimalField( max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True)
        Jul = models.DecimalField( max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True)
        Aug = models.DecimalField( max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True)
        Sep = models.DecimalField( max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True)
        Oct = models.DecimalField( max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True)
        Nov = models.DecimalField( max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True)
        Dec = models.DecimalField( max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True)
        uniqueFields = ['name','CityCategory','type']
        class Meta:
            permissions = (
                ("access_tst", "Access target setting tool."),
                ("run_tst", "Compute new targets."),
                ("validate_tst", "Validate and load new targets."),
        )
        def as_json(self):
            return {0: self.name, 1: self.CityCategory, 2: self.type, 3: self.Jan,4: self.Feb,5: self.Mar,6: self.Apr,7: self.May,8: self.Jun,9: self.Jul,10: self.Aug,11: self.Sep,12: self.Oct,13: self.Nov,14: self.Dec}
```

This value "12000" is indeed the first decimal value of the first row retruned by the database (SQLite).

Any ideas?

Thx,

Comment: What is `as_json()` method? Show the definition please.

Comment: The as_json() method is defined in the model as follow: `def as_json(self):
            return {0: self.name, 1: self.CityCategory, 2: self.type, 3: self.Jan,4: self.Feb,5: self.Mar,6: self.Apr,7: self.May,8: self.Jun,9: self.Jul,10: self.Aug,11: self.Sep,12: self.Oct,13: self.Nov,14: self.Dec}`

Comment: What django version are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7 / Django 1.5.5 / Apache 2 / mod_wsgi.so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to fix the problem is to change `to_json()` method and cast all decimal field values to `str`:

```
def as_json(self):             
    return {0: self.name, 
            1: self.CityCategory, 
            2: self.type, 
            3: str(self.Jan),
            4: str(self.Feb), 
            ...
            14: str(self.Dec)}
```

Comment: Ok, I have updated my code that way. I let you know ASAP if it worked! Thx a lot.

Comment: @pfc yeah, it is basically a workaround. I'm still wondering why `DjangoJSONEncoder` would not serialize decimal fields - it [knows](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/serializers/json.py#106) how to do it.

Comment: This is a workaround but seems like a hack. Why do we have to cast the decimal to a string? This seems technically incorrect, since the correct JSON representation should just be the number? e.g. `f = Decimal('2.0010') -> {"f": 2.0010}` instead `{"f": "2.0010"}`